# How to aggregate number of customers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, data-warehouse

I have transaction data like this:

```
| Time_Stamp          | Customer_ID | Amount | Department | Pay_Method  | Channel    |
|---------------------|-------------|--------|------------|-------------|------------|
| 2018-03-07 14:23:33 | 374856829   | 14.63  | Fruit      | Credit Card | Mobile App |
```

I have written an aggregation procedure like this:

```
INSERT INTO Days
(
    Year,
    Month,
    Day,
    Department,
    Pay_Method,
    Total_Dollars,
    Total_Transactions,
    Total_Customers
)
SELECT
    YEAR(Time_Stamp),
    MONTH(Time_Stamp),
    DAY(Time_Stamp),
    Department,
    Pay_Method,
    SUM(Amount),
    COUNT(*),
    COUNT(DISTINCT(Customer_ID))
FROM
    Transactions
GROUP BY
    YEAR(Time_Stamp),
    MONTH(Time_Stamp),
    DAY(Time_Stamp),
    Department,
    Pay_Method
```

Which populates a data mart table like this:

```
| Year | Month | Day | Department | Pay_Method | Total_Dollars | Total_Transactions | Total_Customers |
|------|-------|-----|------------|------------|---------------|--------------------|-----------------|
| 2018 | 3     | 7   | Home       | Cash       | 2398540.57    | 543084             | 325783          |
| 2018 | 3     | 7   | Home       | Credit     | 7458392.47    | 1587695            | 758643          |
```

So far, so good.

I then have procedures which feed the charts UI like this:

```
SELECT
    Year,
    Month,
    Day,
    SUM(Total_Dollars),
    SUM(Total_Transactions),
    SUM(Total_Customers)
FROM
    Days
WHERE
    IIF(@Department IS NULL, Department, @Department) AND
    IIF(@Pay_Method IS NULL, Pay_Method, @Pay_Method)
GROUP BY
    Year,
    Month,
    Day
```

This all works great for `Total_Transactions` and `Total_Dollars`, but not for `Total_Customers`.

The `Total_Customers` numbers in the Days table are correct in each row, for that specific combination of `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Department` and `Pay_Method`, but when two of those rows are summed together, the total becomes inaccurate, because the same customer may have made multiple transactions using different `Department(s)` and `Pay_Method(s)` on the same date. The numbers become even more inaccurate when adding days together to get monthly customer counts, etc...

I thought the solution would be to try and trick SQL Server into considering "all" as possible values for the various "group by" fields, and played around with group by and case quite a bit but couldn't figure it out. Essentially, in addition to my Days table containing every specific combination of Year, Month, `Day`, `Department` and `Pay_Method`, I also need to generate rows where `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Department` and `Pay_Method` are considered as "any" or "all". Lastly, I don't need to generate rows where `Year` is "any" and `Month` and `Day` are specified (although it wouldn't hurt really), as no one cares for totals of March 7th in any year, etc...

Can someone help me write the query to properly populate my `Days` table?

Comment: can you please share sample source data and its expected output, it will be more helpful than bigger description

Comment: If you don't want to filter by those fields *don't* include them. Such `catch-all` queries *guarantee* bad performance.

Comment: You are describing a typical Sales star schema. First of all, client languages, reporting tools, Excel (eg in pivot tables) can add the required filter conditions. There's no need to use catch-all tricks. Second, in all tutorials you'll see that *dimensions* like Department, Payment_Method can have *hierarchies* based on attributes. You can select all sales that correspond to all credit card providers by adding eg a second-level field that's Cash or CreditCard. Finally Sales isn't Days. Use a *separate* Days/Date/Calendar table. This will make Year-over-Year calculations a lot easier

Comment: Finally, you can use SSAS to create cubes with precalculated aggregates. The `All` level is simply one more pre-calculated value in this case. Tools like Excel's PivotTable can query a cube directly. SSAS also provide calendar logic making Year-over-Year, Month-Over-Month reports almost trivial

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because the "grain" of your model is wrong. Grain is the term given to the level of detail in a fact table.

You always want to store your facts at the finest level of detail, then you can aggregate your data correctly. You were already at that point with your first table.

Rather than aggregating the data (incorrectly) into your second table, simply rewrite or amend that table to break your date/time into the fields you require for reporting.

By the way, if this is truly representative of your data, I suspect that you might actually be hiding an error in your transaction count. You may need a finer level of detail than "department", and I suspect it might be a concept like "product". What would happen to your model if a customer bought both apples and oranges?

Comment: Regarding the finest level of detail... Chart queries from the Transaction table take minutes to complete, even with proper indexing. The table has 80 million rows. The finest level of detail needed in the charts is Daily, so I have a Days table with the data aggregated by day. I have presented the dimensions as I have them. Product is an additional dimension I didn't list for this simplified sample sake. Any tips based on what I just added?